# calculate average per week

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a table in ms-access that keeps data about incoming daily calls. Normally someone can answer 5-7 per day. One of the fields is named "completed_date". When this date is not null that means the call has been answered/completed.

How can I return the average call answer per week?

Comment: In order to get a sensible answer to a query question, you need to include sample data and the hoped for result. Ideally, you should also include the SQL from your attempt to build this query using the query design window in MS Access, with special reference to the sum button (`Σ`) and the F1 key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the DatePart Function to compute week numbers based on your `completed_date` values.

```
SELECT
    DatePart("ww", completed_date) AS week_number,
    Count(*)
FROM YourTable
WHERE completed_date Is Not Null
GROUP BY DatePart("ww", completed_date);
```

That could work for data within a single calendar year.  However, if your data spans more than one year, include `Year(completed_date)` as an additional field expression and GROUP BY item.

Note `DatePart()` accepts optional arguments so you can specify `firstdayofweek` and `firstweekofyear`.  If your organizations week numbering strategy isn't compatible with `DatePart()`, you can create a calendar table to map dates and week numbers, then join the calendar table with your original data source table.